# Python if statement keeps giving else output even when conditions are met

Tags: python, mysql, if-statement

If statement keeps skipping to else even when the conditions are met.
I think it might be the

```
if c1 == 1:
```

as one has not been defined anywhere

this is my command and if statement:

```
c1 = "Select * From tag_logs where reader_id = 'Reader_001' and timestamp > '" + str(t) +"' and tag_no = '55992086130'"
c1 = mycursor.fetchone()
#print(c1)
#mycursor.execute("Select * From tag_logs where reader_id = 'Reader_001' and timestamp >='" + str(t) +"' and tag_no = '55992086130'")

cursor = mydb.cursor(buffered=True)

if c1 == 1:   
    ser.write(b'H')
    print('done')

else:
   ser.write(b'L')
   print('deny')

mycursor.execute(c1)
```

Comment: Have you tried to print `c1` and its type?

Comment: Also, preparing a query with string concatenation is a very bad practice that exposes your program to sql injection.

Comment: ps. The code never lies, We just make wrong assumptions about it. If that statement goes to `else`, then the condition is wrong.

Comment: Aren't you suppose to `execute` before you `fetch()`?

Comment: yes I have tried the c1 print it prints exactly whats needed from the database

Comment: In the 2nd line, the value of `c1` is changes, and then you are checking with `integer`. Are you sure that the `fetchone()` returns an **integer**.

Comment: @Ayat.H and what is it printing?

Comment: I am not sure if fetchone returns an integer

Comment: c1 prints from the db INSERT INTO tag_logs (reader_id, tag_no) VALUES ('Reader_002','55992086130')
Select * From tag_logs where reader_id = 'Reader_001' and timestamp > '2019-04-24 14:12:05.560007' and tag_no = '55992086130'

Answer (score 0):

A sample statement of what I meant:

```
mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM tag_logs WHERE reader_id =?", (t,))
row = mycursor.fetchone()

if row == None:
   print("There are no results for this query")
else:
   ser.write(b'H')
   print('done')
```

Comment: how do I set my result back to zero after a if statement